# Stack analysis tools

Tags: stack

I'm working in automotive field and my Company tends to buy a stack analysis tool (a tool to compute the maximum stack for a given source code or binary). We are using different targets ranging from 8 bits to 32 bits, previously we were using a home made tool, and we are currently evaluating stack analyzer from Absint, 
any other tool suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: What language? What platform/s?

Comment: @Oded AbsInt's tools work at the binary level for a wide range of platforms, hence the OP's omission, but I agree that details would help to provide useful answers.

Comment: The language is C, under different platforms (NEC V850, Freescale HC12, and many others).. So the preferred tool should be platform independent, like Absint Stackanalyzer that work on a binary code.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how "platform independent" and "work on (different) binary code" are related.  If AbsInt's tool are *cross* platform because they've done a lot of engineering work, and that's useful, that's fine.

Comment: @Pascal: You seem to know something about the AbsInt product. How does it handle computing anything when it encounters an indirect jump in binary code?

Comment: @Ira Yes, "works on binary code" only lets you forget about the source language, not the complete platform. AbsInt's family of tools also take advantage of the original source to ease user interaction (for supported compilers only). And indirect jumps are handled by assuming execution continues at the possible targets computed by the analyzer. The tool suite is powered by a binary-level value analysis. This said, the set of possible targets of an indirect branch is typically the kind of information you end up having to provide to the tool as an hint.

Comment: @Pascal:  If the object file has any kind of nonempty set (e.g., 100) of indirect jumps, that seems like an awful lot of information to have to provide.

Comment: @Ira As I try to remember the one-day class I once took, it seems to me that indirect jump targets are obtained from the source code when available (and when the compiler is supported).

Answer (score 1):

If you can be satisfied with the kind of approximation that can be made by doing the analysis at the source level, and you are using C, [Frama-C's value analysis](http://frama-c.com/value.html) can give you an exhaustive list of call stacks (in terms of source functions) that can happen at run-time.

Frama-C also provides the building blocks to quickly convert these source-level possible call stacks into stack depths if you know precisely how your C compiler works: for each function, you can programmatically inspect local variables, arguments, ...